# Jquery .remove() not working in table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying add new lines and remove on a table.
I have that code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var n_obs = $("input[name$='[obs]']").length;
var n_esp = $("select[name$='[e_status]']").length;

addEsp = (function() {
    $("#tb_especialidade").append("<tr><td>" + n_esp + "</td></tr>");
    n_esp++;
});

addObs = (function() {
    $("#tb_status").append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + n_obs + "</td>" +
            "<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancelar\" onclick=\"rem();\"></td>" +
            "</tr>"
            );
    n_obs++;
});

rem = (function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
});
```

For add new elements is working, but not to remove.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you check your `rem()` ever get called?

Comment: You're binding the function to elements of class btnrem, but you don't have any element with that class assigned.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Yeah, he activate an alert test.

Comment: @eyp, I forget that piece of code, from another test. removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another approach.

Pass `this` as an element as a reference to `rem()`

```
"<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancelar\" onclick=\"rem(this);\"></td>" 
--------------------------------------------------------------^----------
```

Where `this` refers to the current element, then it will be easy to find the `tr` closest parent in your `rem()`.

Change script to this

```
rem = (function(elem) {
    $(elem).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use separate `click` event here instead of using nested `onclick` function and apply [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since your input button has been added dynamically:

```
$('#tb_status').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: I don't think it requires delegation since OP has added `onclick` at runtime!

Comment: I just want to suggest him a better approach IMO :)